# Comparación Strings ¿Por que no funciona en Android 7.0 y en otras versiones si?

Tags: android, android-studio, json

Este ejercicio sencillo no funciona en Android 7.0 y en versiones anteriores de Android si funciona, ¿por qué puede ser?`

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String cadena = params[0];
        URL url = null;//
        String devuelve = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(cadena);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                    "(Linux: Android 7.0; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");

            int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");

                if (resultJSON == "1") {
                    JSONArray alumnosJSON = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray("alumnos");
                    for (int i = 0; i < alumnosJSON.length(); i++) {
                        devuelve = devuelve + alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_alumno") + " " +
                                alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre") + " " +
                                alumnosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("direccion") + "\n";

                   }
                } else if (resultJSON == "2") {
                    devuelve = "No hay resultados";
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return devuelve;
    }`
```

En version 7.0, cuando compruebo que resultJSON == "1" me saca del if como si no fuera = 1 y sí lo es.

Cuando pruebo con otra version de Android o quito el if, funciona correctamente

Comment: Como se dijo en una respuesta, las cadenas debes compararlas con `equals`, pero veo otra cosa extraña en tu código:  `} else if (resultJSON == "2") {` y  luego no hay más `else` para cerrar. Debería ser: `if () {...} else if () { ... }  else { ... }`

Comment: en la parte del if cuando comparar un Spring con == esta mal creada bueno en si si funciona pero porque esta mal ? sencillo porque esa es la forma para comparar enteros,flotantes,etc y no cadenas la mejor forma es usar equals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparar un String como tu haces es poco mas que un suicidio. Para comparar String se hace asi:

```
if (resultJSON.equals("1"))
```

o asi

```
if (resultJSON.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
```

la diferencia es que el segundo caso no tiene encuenta si la cadena a comparar tiene mayusculas o minisculas, es case insensitive.

Prueba y veras como seguro te funciona.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Por que no funciona en Android 7.0 y en otras versiones si?

**En realidad no funcionaría en ninguna versión de Android**,

```
if (resultJSON == "1") {
...
...
 } else if (resultJSON == "2") {
      ...
}
```

**la comparación de variables tipo String se realiza mediante el método [**equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))**.**

```
if (resultJSON.equals("1")) {
...
...
 } else if (resultJSON.equals("2")) {
      ...
}
```

Usar [equalsIgnoreCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)), no es necesario en este caso ya que aplica para caracteres alfabéticos.